# Extracting the value stored in the /tikz/x option

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfkeys, coordinates

It is possible to change the x distance within TikZ internal coordinate system by passing the /tikz/x= key to the tikzpicture environment.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=14pt]
% Picture code
\end{tikzpicture}
```

I need to get the value stored inside this key within a picture to perform some calculations. Is it possible to do so ? What I'm looking for is something like this...

```
 \begin{tikzpicture}[x=14pt]
 % Some command to get the x value and store it in a macro for example /myx

 %\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/x} or \pgfkeys{/tikz/x/.get=\myx} don't seem to work

 % Use the \myx in calculations
 \end{tikzpicture}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately the value isn't stored inside the key, as it is parsed immediately (the argument to the |x| key can be a coordinate) and then passed on to `\pgfsetxvec`.

But there are still a couple of ways to get the x-component of the coordinate system.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\makeatletter
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=14pt]
\pgfqpointxy{1}{0}\pgfgetlastxy\x\y
\node {$x_1$: \x, $x_2$: \the\pgf@xx};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]